# jquery: $(input).keydown fails to set handler on radio button, same code works for text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a long form that is broken into sections that are in jquery accordion panels. When the user is done filling in the form in one panel they go to the next panel and fill in the form there.  The accordion breaks the long form into steps. But, when the user completes the last input on one panel pressing the tab key won't take them to the next field, in the next panel, unless I do it programmaticly.  For the inputs that are type text, the following code works well.  But, where the inputs are type radio it is not working.  This following code first assigns the keydown function to a text box, then fails to assign it to a set of three radio buttons, then succeeds again to assign it to a text box.

What's frustrating is that if I copy and paste the middle block into the chrome javascript console then it will work like a charm.

So, what's the problem?

```
document.onReady(function(){
            $('#f-phone').keydown(function(e){
                 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                 if ( code === 9) {
                 my_accordion.accordion("option", "active", 3);
                 }
             });

            $('input[name=shipping_method]').keydown(function(e){
                 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                 console.log('code is '+code);
             });

            $('#f-special_instructions').keydown(function(e){
                 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                 if ( code === 9) {
                 my_accordion.accordion("option", "active", 5);
                 }
             });
});
```

HTML follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <label class="req" for="f-shipping_phone" id="label-shipping-phone">Phone (Recipient)<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
  <input type="text" name="shipping_phone"  size="35" maxlength="35" autocomplete="telephone-full" class="addr_phone" id="f-shipping_phone" />
</div>
<h2 id="ship-options" id="h2_shipping">Shipping Options</h2>
<div class="rowSet" id="checkout-shipping-level">
<div class="row" id="shipping_type">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:300px">
    <caption>Times are estimates once shipped.</caption>
    <tr align="center" valign="top">
    <td>
    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="4" id="ship4" >
    </td> <td>
    <label for="ship4">Standard</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" valign="top">
    <td>
    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="7" id="ship7" checked="checked">
    </td> <td>
    <label for="ship7">Saver</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" valign="top">
    <td>
    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="2" id="ship2" >
    </td> <td>
    <label for="ship2">Expedited</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would put the keydown handler on the whole form. When It detects the last element within a div then move on to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that even when I apply the handler via the javascript console it will disappear upon closing that accordion panel.  So, I believe there is no solution to this one unless it is handling the keystrokes at a different level, as one commenter posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#f-phone').keydown(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( code === 9) {
        my_accordion.accordion("option", "active", 3);
    }
});

$('input:radio[name=shipping_method]').keydown(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    console.log('code is '+code);
    alert('code is '+code);
});

$('#f-special_instructions').keydown(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( code === 9) {
        my_accordion.accordion("option", "active", 5);
    }
}); });
```

You can check it in fiddler: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ynksq4ku/)

You are attaching only "keydown" event to the radio buttons. You might as well attach "click" or "change" events to the radio buttons.

Comment: Thank you for this code. I copy and pasted that into my document.ready handler and it did not seem to work any better than my original code.  My guess is that adding ':radio' adds nothing because the selector is already correct and sufficient with out it.  If it works in fiddler then it must be the same as working when entered on the console line, right?  The doc.ready handler attaches the onkeydown handler to the other inputs, what is the matter with these radio buttons?

Comment: Have you tried changing the "document.onReady(function()" to "$(document).ready(function()"

Comment: oh, that "onReady", in the question, is a typo.  The code is actually as you have suggested.

Comment: Which version of jQuery library are you using? Can try using the exact code below:                                                                $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('input:radio[name=shipping_method]').keydown(function(e){
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        console.log('code is '+code);
        alert('code is '+code);
    });
    
});

Comment: Also check if there are other javascript errors on the page.